# How can I use nohup to run process as a background process in linux?

Tags: linux

I use this command to run my work.

```
(time bash executeScript 1 input fileOutput $> scrOutput) &> timeUse.txt
```

While, 1 is a number of process that I use to run this work. I have to change the number of process for each run. At each time it use long time to complete. Then I want to run it as background process.

How can I do it?

I tried:

```
nohup ((time bash executeScript 1 input fileOutput $> scrOutput) &> timeUse.txt)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: nohup <command> & disown

Answer (score 72):

In general, I use `nohup CMD &` to run a nohup background process. However, when the command is in a form that `nohup` won't accept then I run it through `bash -c "..."`.

For example:

```
nohup bash -c "(time ./script arg1 arg2 > script.out) &> time_n_err.out" &
```

stdout from the script gets written to `script.out`, while stderr and the output of `time` goes into `time_n_err.out`.

So, in your case:

```
nohup bash -c "(time bash executeScript 1 input fileOutput > scrOutput) &> timeUse.txt" &
```

Answer (score 38):

You can write a script and then use `nohup ./yourscript &` to execute

For example:

```
vi yourscript
```

put

```
#!/bin/bash
script here
```

you may also need to change permission to run script on server

```
chmod u+rwx yourscript
```

finally

```
nohup ./yourscript &
```

Comment: what does the '&' do in this?

Comment: @acodejdatam, it starts the process in the background without waiting for it to finish

Answer (score 8):

- Use screen: Start `screen`, start your script, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>. Reattach with `screen -r`.
- Make a script that takes your "1" as a parameter, run `nohup yourscript`:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  (time bash executeScript $1 input fileOutput $> scrOutput) &> timeUse.txt
  ```

Answer (score 6):

The modern and easy to use approach that allows managing multiple processes and has a nice terminal UI is [hapless](https://github.com/bmwant/hapless) utility.

Install with `pip install hapless` (or `python3 -m pip install hapless`) and just run

```bash
$ hap run my-command  # e.g. hap run python my_long_running_script.py
$ hap status  # check all the launched processes
```

See [docs](https://github.com/bmwant/hapless/blob/main/USAGE.md) for more info.

[image: ui]