# What is the best way to async upload files in background with PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous, beanstalkd

In my app users will upload files (small and large). I wolud like to store file in S3 or FTP or any other storage service.

My plan is to upload files from client with AJAX (with progress bar) to my PHP server and then transfer them in background to destination storage. And I want to do the last part asynchronously (in the background). I also need to do some tasks (like database update and cleanup) after uploading files from my server to storage.

My previous approach was to use **nohup** (something like: [How can I use nohup to run process as a background process in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164985/how-can-i-use-nohup-to-run-process-as-a-background-process-in-linux)) but it has some disadvantages and I preffer not to use it.

I am using Laravel, so I am thinking about queues with beanstalkd. I know queues are good for sending emails, image processing and similar stuff but I never used it before so I don't know if it is good for background files upload.  Is this good approach? Or maybe there are better ways to do that?

Comment: have you tried [laravel.io](http://laravel.io/forum/03-18-2014-best-logic-for-implmenting-upload-progress-bar) which suggest using jQuery file upload

Comment: client upload is not a problem. The problem is background upload from my PHP server to remote storage like S3.

Comment: Using queues isn't really a solution as you still have to send the whole file through to the queue or store it in a tmp spot. The only thing you can do is store it in a tmp location than have a queue trigger to upload it to S3.

Comment: Well yeah, this is what I am asking about. I have the files stored in temp location on my PHP server and I need to upload it to remote S3 in background using for example upload function triggered with a queue. I know I can use queues for this, but I have no knowledge what are the disadvantages of this approach. Or maybe there are better approaches.

Comment: Queues sound like a good way to go about this. Only disadvantages your putting load on your apache again. Which if many large files are uploaded could become a bottleneck. Another way is to let the queue trigger an script (bash...) and and use S3(or other file syncing tool) once the transfer is complete check if it is actually on the remote server and than delete it from the tmp dir. Just how I  would do it.

Comment: I think I was doing similar thing so far. I was running PHP script with nohup (php script from command line, without apache). Anyone has some other ideas? And please someone tell me why my question has a "-1" effort grade?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68267/discussion-between-douglasdc3-and-thejohnny).

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try on Dispatcher. Take a look at here:

https://github.com/Indatus/dispatcher

From the website: "Dispatcher is a Laravel artisan command scheduling tool used to schedule artisan commands within your project so you don't need to touch your crontab when deploying."

Comment: You can't pass UploadedFile to queques: ```Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed```