# `nohup node build/index.js &` does not execute in the background

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, gitlab, nohup

Inside a **GitLab** CI pipeline, I run the `nohup` command to start a **NodeJS** server. I have experimented with several versions of the command. None of the versions ran completely in the background. For some reasons they always stay running in the terminal.

This is the command I used most recently:

```
ORIGIN=http://$PUBLIC_HOST:$PUBLIC_PORT nohup node build/index.js \
     --port $PUBLIC_PORT | ts >> build/log.txt 2>&1 &
```

I have tried with and without the pipe at the end.

Which version of this command logs the output of the node process in the background together with timestamps without hanging the terminal?

*PS: I am not able to use `pm2` or other daemons with online metrics for security considerations.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the answer to [How can I use nohup to run process as a background process in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164985/how-can-i-use-nohup-to-run-process-as-a-background-process-in-linux), I have found a way to let it run by wrapping the core command into `bash -c "command"`.

The command is now

```bash
ORIGIN=http://$PUBLIC_HOST:$PUBLIC_PORT \ 
    nohup bash -c "node build/index.js --port $PUBLIC_PORT | ts"  \
    >> build/out.log 2>&1 &
```

With a variation to split errors and logs based on https://askubuntu.com/questions/349262/run-a-nohup-command-over-ssh-then-disconnect with

```bash
ORIGIN=http://$PUBLIC_HOST:$PUBLIC_PORT \
    nohup bash -c "node build/index.js --port $PUBLIC_PORT | ts" \
    1>>build/out.log \
    2>>build/err.log &
```