# Run flask application on linux server with nohup

Tags: python, linux, shell

I am trying to run my flask application on my linux server using nohup , but each time i run my flask application with nohup , my server will require me to kill with cntrl + c in order for me to do other things

assuming i have 2 file in my server
path(home/app/)

1. flask_app.py [ which is my flask application ]
2. flk.sh

inside my run.sh i have included

```
nohup python /home/app/flask_app.py
```

when i run my shell script in my server which is `sh flk.sh`

my system will hang as per shown in below image if i dont exit it as its running and all activity will go inside nohup.out
[image]

how can i run nohup on my flask application without me having to use cntrl + c to exit to run other commands.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use nohup to run process as a background process in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164985/how-can-i-use-nohup-to-run-process-as-a-background-process-in-linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually want to use `nohup command arg1 arg2 &`. You're just missing the ampersand.

Briefly, `nohup` prevents the OS from killing your job, `&` sends the job in the background, so it isn't tied to your current shell.

Comment: Yes this is it, i was missing the & at the back